# What is Lucene query to search for a wild character string

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

In Kibana I am trying to pull the my application log messages that had masked fields.

Example log message: 
    ***statusMessage=, displayMessage=, securityInfoOutput=securityPin=pin=****, pinHint=*************

I want to search and pull the messages that have masked data - more than two consecutive *'s in the message.

Trying with search term message:"pin=\*\*\*\*"

but it didn't work

Comment: tried with search term message:"\\*\\*\\*\\*". but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking of search in the same way you'd type `CTRL+F` and search in a file. Search engines don't work that way. Search works based on exact matches of *tokens*. Tokens typically correspond to words extracted from text.

You can control how text is transformed into tokens using a process known as [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). Analysis runs text through tokenization and various filters that decide how text is broken up into tokens and other pieces of metadata associated with each token.

This [blog post](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/09/18/the-simple-power-of-elasticsearch-analyzers/) I wrote might help put some of this into context.